# How to append/update query parameters in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I'm using query parameters in my app that I want to retain/update when navigating and updating settings. I can add a parameter without any problems by doing the following.

```
onNavigate() {
this.router.navigate(['reports'], {queryParams: {'report': this.chart}, preserveQueryParams:true});
}
```

However I want to be able to change the report param and append new params onto the url throughout my app.

Using `preserveQueryParams: true` makes my params read-only. I want to be able to update current params and add new ones without losing anything unless I clear them.

How can I do this without losing my currently set params?

Answer (score 0):

I guess `preserveQueryParams` is not meant to append/update `queryParams` on behalf of application.

You have to write your logic to get existing query params and update it as per your requirement and then pass while navigating.

```
   this.route.queryParams.subscribe(qparams => {
     this.currentQueryParams= qparams;
   });

    updatedqueryParams = // use this.currentQueryParams update it to append\update new stuff
    let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: updatedqueryParams
    };

    // Navigate to the login page with extras
    this.router.navigate(['<some path>'], navigationExtras);
```

what `preserveQueryParams` is meant for is to pass current Global queryParams you are routing to,

so if current URL is

```
 dashboard?debug=true&somevar=1
```

and you write something like below,

```
  this.router.navigate(['admin'],  {
        preserveQueryParams: true
      }
 );
```

the new route will be, so it is preserving the Query params.

```
admin?debug=true&somevar=1
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

preserveQueryParams has been deprecated, use queryParamsHandling instead.

queryParamsHandling is used to config strategy to handle the query parameters for the next navigation.

https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras